# Damaged HDD - How can I shut down windows 10 fully so that I can boot UBUNTU USB?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, boot-repair

Brand new LINUX user here.

I created a bootable UBUNTU USB drive with 16.04 so that I could boot into a PC with a damaged boot HDD (Windows 10), but fails to boot,to see what files might be recoverable.

I booted successfully off the UBUNTU USB and when I got to the window that looks a lot like File Explorer I saw, 1TB Ext Bay1 (which contains an external HDD that is working), Computer and Gateway (which is my machine).

It appears that Windows 10 is in hibernation mode and I need to get it out of that mode and shut it down completely.  I don't seem to be able to do that.

I wanted to see if the files on the C drive were still accessible.
When I click on either Gateway or 1TB Ext Bay1, I get a message "Unable to access “Gateway

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/ubuntu/Gateway: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999" "/dev/sda3" "/media/ubuntu/Gateway"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option."
```

It's the same message when I try this with 1TB Ext Bay1, except that it says 1TB Ext Bay1.

I did try right clicking and selecting Mount, but the same message came up.

Is there a way I can get out of hibernation mode to shut it down completely?

Thanks

Steve

---

Follow up after trying Sudodus's suggestions:

Thank you for your feedback.

I tried sudo mount /dev/sda3 -o ro rw,users,umask=000 /mnt, went to the file manager, to Computer -> /mnt, but there was nothing there. I then entered the following, but am not sure where to go from here (there's still nothing showing in /mnt).

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda3 -o ro rw,users,umask=000 /mnt

Usage:
 mount [-lhV]
 mount -a [options]
 mount [options] [--source] <source> | [--target] <directory>
 mount [options] <source> <directory>
 mount <operation> <mountpoint> [<target>]

Mount a filesystem.

Options:
 -a, --all               mount all filesystems mentioned in fstab
 -c, --no-canonicalize   don't canonicalize paths
 -f, --fake              dry run; skip the mount(2) syscall
 -F, --fork              fork off for each device (use with -a)
 -T, --fstab <path>      alternative file to /etc/fstab
 -i, --internal-only     don't call the mount.<type> helpers
 -l, --show-labels       show also filesystem labels
 -n, --no-mtab           don't write to /etc/mtab
 -o, --options <list>    comma-separated list of mount options
 -O, --test-opts <list>  limit the set of filesystems (use with -a)
 -r, --read-only         mount the filesystem read-only (same as -o ro)
 -t, --types <list>      limit the set of filesystem types
     --source <src>      explicitly specifies source (path, label, uuid)
     --target <target>   explicitly specifies mountpoint
 -v, --verbose           say what is being done
 -w, --rw, --read-write  mount the filesystem read-write (default)

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

Source:
 -L, --label <label>     synonym for LABEL=<label>
 -U, --uuid <uuid>       synonym for UUID=<uuid>
 LABEL=<label>           specifies device by filesystem label
 UUID=<uuid>             specifies device by filesystem UUID
 PARTLABEL=<label>       specifies device by partition label
 PARTUUID=<uuid>         specifies device by partition UUID
 <device>                specifies device by path
 <directory>             mountpoint for bind mounts (see --bind/rbind)
 <file>                  regular file for loopdev setup

Operations:
 -B, --bind              mount a subtree somewhere else (same as -o bind)
 -M, --move              move a subtree to some other place
 -R, --rbind             mount a subtree and all submounts somewhere else
 --make-shared           mark a subtree as shared
 --make-slave            mark a subtree as slave
 --make-private          mark a subtree as private
 --make-unbindable       mark a subtree as unbindable
 --make-rshared          recursively mark a whole subtree as shared
 --make-rslave           recursively mark a whole subtree as slave
 --make-rprivate         recursively mark a whole subtree as private
 --make-runbindable      recursively mark a whole subtree as unbindable

For more details see mount(8).
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -ls
Model: ATA ST31500341AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  17.2GB  17.2GB  primary  ntfs         diag
 2      17.2GB  17.3GB  105MB   primary  ntfs         boot
 3      17.3GB  1500GB  1483GB  primary  ntfs


Model:  USB FLASH DRIVE (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 4010MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      16.4kB  4010MB  4010MB  primary  fat32        boot


Model: ATA SAMSUNG HD103UJ (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo umount /mnt
umount: /mnt: not mounted
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda3 -o ro rw,users,umask=000 /mnt

Usage:
 mount [-lhV]
 mount -a [options]
 mount [options] [--source] <source> | [--target] <directory>
 mount [options] <source> <directory>
 mount <operation> <mountpoint> [<target>]

Mount a filesystem.

Options:
 -a, --all               mount all filesystems mentioned in fstab
 -c, --no-canonicalize   don't canonicalize paths
 -f, --fake              dry run; skip the mount(2) syscall
 -F, --fork              fork off for each device (use with -a)
 -T, --fstab <path>      alternative file to /etc/fstab
 -i, --internal-only     don't call the mount.<type> helpers
 -l, --show-labels       show also filesystem labels
 -n, --no-mtab           don't write to /etc/mtab
 -o, --options <list>    comma-separated list of mount options
 -O, --test-opts <list>  limit the set of filesystems (use with -a)
 -r, --read-only         mount the filesystem read-only (same as -o ro)
 -t, --types <list>      limit the set of filesystem types
     --source <src>      explicitly specifies source (path, label, uuid)
     --target <target>   explicitly specifies mountpoint
 -v, --verbose           say what is being done
 -w, --rw, --read-write  mount the filesystem read-write (default)

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

Source:
 -L, --label <label>     synonym for LABEL=<label>
 -U, --uuid <uuid>       synonym for UUID=<uuid>
 LABEL=<label>           specifies device by filesystem label
 UUID=<uuid>             specifies device by filesystem UUID
 PARTLABEL=<label>       specifies device by partition label
 PARTUUID=<uuid>         specifies device by partition UUID
 <device>                specifies device by path
 <directory>             mountpoint for bind mounts (see --bind/rbind)
 <file>                  regular file for loopdev setup

Operations:
 -B, --bind              mount a subtree somewhere else (same as -o bind)
 -M, --move              move a subtree to some other place
 -R, --rbind             mount a subtree and all submounts somewhere else
 --make-shared           mark a subtree as shared
 --make-slave            mark a subtree as slave
 --make-private          mark a subtree as private
 --make-unbindable       mark a subtree as unbindable
 --make-rshared          recursively mark a whole subtree as shared
 --make-rslave           recursively mark a whole subtree as slave
 --make-rprivate         recursively mark a whole subtree as private
 --make-runbindable      recursively mark a whole subtree as unbindable

For more details see mount(8).
```

Comment: There's a typo in your mount command. It should be: `sudo mount /dev/sda3 -o ro,rw,users,umask=000 /mnt` (note the comma instead of the space between the mount options). While this command is syntactically correct, it still specifies two conflicting options `ro` (read-only) and `rw` (read-write). I think the last one to appear in the option list overrides the earlier one.

Comment: Sorry for the typing error - and thanks for discovering it, David.

Answer (score 0):

Do what the automatic tip suggests: mount the partition /dev/sda3 read-only with the 'ro' mount option. Start a terminal window with the hotkey combination

`ctrl` + `alt` + `t`

You can use the standard mount point `/mnt` according to this command line in the terminal window.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 -o ro,users,umask=000 /mnt
```

After that you should be able to read and copy the files in /dev/sda3 with command line tools or with the file manager, 'the window that looks a lot like File Explorer'. Select 'Computer' in the left pane, then browse to the directory '/mnt', and there you should file Windows files.

-o-

If /dev/sda3 is not the main Windows directory you can get help from the output of the following command (in the terminal window)

```
sudo parted -ls
```

where you see the partition numbers and what kind of partition they are.

```
sudo umount /mnt

sudo mount /dev/sdxn -o ro,users,umask=000 /mnt
```

where **x** is the drive letter and **n** is the number of the partition, for example 1, 2 or 3, that you think is the correct one, the main Windows partition C:

Comment: Good luck! Let us know how it works :-)

Comment: Hi Sudodus.  Thanks for your help.  Please see the edit to my original post based on what you posted here.

Comment: Aren't there a syntax error in the mount command '$ sudo mount /dev/sda3 -o ro rw,users,umask=000 /mnt'  .. should be '$ sudo mount /dev/sda3 -o ro,users,umask=000 /mnt' I think,

Comment: Is there?  What needs to be fixed?

Comment: I'm very sorry for the typing error (due to copy/paste and not checking enough). It is fixed now in my answer, and I think it will work for you, spodeworld, if you use the correct command line for mounting.

Comment: @sudodus - Thanks so much!  I was able to see my drive with udo mount /dev/sda3 -o ro,users,umask=000 /mnt!  I wasn't sure if I could rescue files from my crashed disk but since I am able to see them, so it looks promising! Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad that you can see your files. Good luck copying them to a safe place :-)